# ZK - inject Spring beans directly into ZK beans

Tags: spring, zk

Is it possible to inject Spring beans directly into ZK backing beans?

In tutorials such as [this](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small%20Talks/2006/October/Contact%20List%20with%20ZK%20and%20Spring) I've found only an example, where application context was extracted manually from web application complex, which very unelegant and unflexible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, the **VariableResolver** is working, it is however hard to find, how to use it properly.

First, I had to include header in .zul file:

```
<?variable-resolver class="org.zkoss.zkplus.spring.DelegatingVariableResolver"?>
```

Then, use ${controllerBeanName} in **apply** attribute, f.e.

```
<window id="win" title="Typy mieszkań" width="750px" border="normal"
      apply="${appartmentTypeController}">
```

In my case, appartmentTypeController is bean extending GeneralForwardComposer, defined in spring context.

Answer (score 2):

did you try the **Variable-Resolver** ?? i found an article about it

http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2010/December/Integrate_ZK_Spreadsheet2.0.0_with_Spring

Comment: This is not exactly what I wanted. I need spring beans in ZK's composers.

Comment: how about this one ? check the "Using SpringUtil" , this might can help you :) http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer's%20Reference/Integration/Spring

Comment: But this SpringUtils is exactly what I was trying to avoid, manually taking ApplicationContext and variables from it, it's inversion of inversion of Control :)

Comment: seems need to they belong to different context.

Answer (score 0):

May ZK-DL http://zk.datalite.cz/zk-dl library help you? It takes it's own approach to Spring integration, not the original ZK way.